# href not working in IE

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer

I have a php site. I have a flat file for reading selections to dynamially build up a menu. Only problem I now have is that the link to load the next page does not work.

```
echo "<tr><td>$chunk[2]</td><td>$chunk[3]</td><td><a href= \"$chunk[4]\"><input type=\"submit\" class=\"input\" value=\"View Details\"/></a></td></tr>";
```

The line above does not display too well in here, so i have cut it down into 5 lines below. In my code though it is all on one line. [just pointing this out]

```
echo "<tr><td>$chunk[2]</td>";  
echo "<td>$chunk[3]</td><td>";
echo "<a href= \"$chunk[4]\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"input\" value=\"View Details\"/>";
echo "</a></td></tr>";
```

My text file is:

```
dogs|animals|shelter|owner|dog1.php
```

I have since removed the following line, whihc resolved the issue

```
 <input type=\"submit\" class=\"input\" value=\"View Details\"/>
```

I have other buttons on the site which for consistency, I would like to keep the same. 
Any idea why IE does not like this, or is there a way to fix this?

my CSS:

```
.input:hover { background: #D8A96E; }
.input:active { color:#D8A96E; }
.input {
    border: 1px #48561D;
    border-style:inset;
    background: #778E30;
    width: 100px;
    color: #FFFFFF }
```

Comment: Why on earth do you have submit button inside `a` tag??

Comment: When you say 'not working', what exactly happens or doesn't happen? Have you ran [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) on your markup?

Comment: Also... if you're putting your `submit` tag inside your `a` tag purely so you can make the link appear the same as your button surely you can just style the anchor with an `id` or `class` attribute to look the same as the button?

Comment: IE is quite sensitive for invalid markup. Just remove buttons from inside `a` and everything will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you imply that this works in other browsers? I would be surprised.

For a quick fix, change the `<a>` tag into a `<form>` tag, like this:

```
...
echo "<form action=\"$chunk[4]\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"input\" value=\"View Details\"/>";
echo "</form></td></tr>";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A submit button and an `<a>` tag do different things.

If your submit button is submitting a form, remove the `<a>` tag.

If you want a button that sends you to a new page without submitting a form, do something like:

```
echo "<script>
  function sendTo(link)
  {
     window.location.href = link
  }
</script>
<input type=\"button\" class=\"input\" value=\"View Details\" onclick=\"sendTo('$chunk[4]')\"/>";
```

Comment: <input type=\"button\"... /> would be better suited for that.

Comment: Good point, I have edited it. `submit` is functional, but `button` has a more obvious purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you're injecting a submit button into the text portion of your link...no need to do that.

if you want the button to take you where you need to go, change the action attribute on your form.  Alternatively you can use a "button" element and use JS to send the user to the location that you desire.